# Metodo fillna para convertir un Nan en entero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Mi problema a resolver trata de un DataFrame de la lista de descargas de modelos, como este: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el cual tengo que crear un DataFrame resultado que obtenga por cada modelo: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello he hecho este código:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
def calcular_estadisticas(descargas:pd.DataFrame)->pd.DataFrame:
    # Paso 1: cargar los datos
    df = pd.DataFrame(descargas)
    
    # TRUE y FALSE son strings por lo que hay que convertirlos a booleanos
    # Convertir TRUE a True y FALSE a False
    df['COMENTARIO'] = df['COMENTARIO'].map({'TRUE': True, 'FALSE': False})
    
    # Paso 2: filtrar los datos
    df_pagados = df[df["PAGO"] > 0]
    
    # Paso 3: calcular las estadísticas
    agg_dict = {
        "PAGO": ["count", "mean", "max", "min"],
        "ESTRELLAS": ["mean", "std"],
        # Reemplazamos count por sum
        "COMENTARIO": ["sum"]
    }
    stats = df_pagados.groupby("MODELO").agg(agg_dict)
    
    # Paso 4: crear el DataFrame resultado
    resultado = pd.DataFrame({
        "CANTIDAD": stats["PAGO"]["count"].astype(int),
        "PROMEDIO": stats["PAGO"]["mean"].round(2),
        "MAXIMO": stats["PAGO"]["max"].round(2),
        "MINIMO": stats["PAGO"]["min"].round(2),
        "ESTRELLAS": stats["ESTRELLAS"]["mean"].round(2),
        "DESV. ESTRELLAS": stats["ESTRELLAS"]["std"].fillna(0).round(2),
        # Reemplazamos count por sum
        "COMENTARIOS": stats["COMENTARIO"]["sum"].astype(int)
    }, index=stats.index)
    
    # Ordenar los resultados alfabéticamente por nombre de modelo
    resultado = resultado.sort_index()
    
    return resultado
```

Tras ejecutar este código obtengo un error de este tipo y no se como corregirlo, si alguien me podría ayudar gracias.
Para poner un contexto si hay solo un dato no podemos calcular la desviacion estandar, entonces aparecerá Nan que debe ser sustituido por 0.0, pero claro no encuentro el error de porque no lo hace
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué datos estás ingresando a la función? Con los que pusiste en tu pregunta funciona correctamente.

Comment: No puedo darte la información sobre los datos que estoy ingresando porque lo hace un corrector, el cual no me especifica nada solo si hay error o si es correcto

Comment: He probado con los datos generados en el enunciado y funciona pero no entiendo la parte del corrector, muchas gracias.

Comment: Es que el error que muestra el sistema de evaluación creo que no tiene sentido, `NA` no significa nada para `pandas` podría ser `NaN` pero ya probé el código poniendo `NaN` en todas las columnas y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Creo que no me deja utilizar fillna, conoces algún otro método para remplazarlo?

Comment: Ah, creo saber lo que sucede. Intenta cambiar los `astype(int)` por `astype('Int64')`. Así: `"CANTIDAD": stats["PAGO"]["count"].astype('Int64')` y `"COMENTARIOS": stats["COMENTARIO"]["sum"].astype('Int64')` y me dices si te funciona para explicarte

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error, he probado otra forma de hacerlo y solo me queda la desviación estandar, ns si podrías ayudarme

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144297/discussion-between-salvador-soriano-brotons-and-heytalepazguato).

Answer (score 0):

No es la opción más elegante (se que existe)... se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd


def calcular_estadisticas(descargas:dict)->pd.DataFrame:
  '''Descripción detallada de la función'''

  if isinstance(descargas, dict):
    # Creamos un dataFrame con los datos de «diccionario»
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=descargas, orient='columns')

    # Para los (pagos==0) cambiamos el cero (0) por NaN
    df['Modelo']= df['Modelo'].where(df['Pago']>0)
    # Eliminamos los valores NaN
    df = df.drop('Usuario', axis=1).dropna()

    ### Agrupamos por 'Modelo' y calculamos: (minimos, maximos, promedios,
    # desviaciones std) de las columnas ('Pago' 'Estrellas' 'Comentario')
    pago = df[['Modelo', 'Pago']].groupby('Modelo').agg(['count','mean','max', 'min']).fillna(0).sort_index()
    # Eliminamos el nivel superior creado en las columnas
    pago.columns = pago.columns.droplevel()
    # Cambiamos el nombre de las columnas
    pago.columns = ['CANTIDAD', 'PROMEDIO', 'MAXIMO', 'MINIMO']

    
    estrellas = df[['Modelo', 'Estrellas']].groupby('Modelo').agg(['max','std']).fillna(0).sort_index()
    estrellas.columns = estrellas.columns.droplevel()
    estrellas.columns = ['ESTRELLAS', 'DEV.ESTRELLAS']

    comentarios = df[['Modelo', 'Comentario']].groupby('Modelo').agg(['sum']).fillna(0).sort_index()
    comentarios.columns = comentarios.columns.droplevel()
    comentarios.columns = ['COMENTARIOS']
    
    # Concatenomos lo dataframes «pago», «estrellas» y «comentarios» 
    df = pd.concat([pago, estrellas, comentarios], axis=1)

     
    return df

  raise TypeError( "‼\n\n  Tipo de parametro incorrecto...\n"\
                      f"\n\t«descargas» es:        {str(type(descargas))} ✘"\
                       "\n\t«descargas» debe ser:  <class 'dict'> ✔\n")





def main():
  '''Funcion principal'''
  diccionario = { 'Modelo': ['Bus urbano #27','Silla tipo bar','Piano','Fuente con flores','Bus urbano #27','Puesto de Yogurt','Playground','Bus urbano #27'],
                 'Usuario': ['Ted Mosby','Art Vandelay','Art Vandelay','Michael','Mark Brendanawicz','Michael','LeCorbusier_2020',''],
                 'Pago': [24.99, 4.99, 4.99, 0, 12, 0, 14, 0],
                 'Estrellas': [5, 3.5,3.5,5,4,5,4.5,1],
                 'Comentario': [True]+[False]*2+[True]*5 }
  
  calcular_estadisticas(diccionario)





if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

La función retornaría:

```
                CANTIDAD  PROMEDIO  MAXIMO  MINIMO  ESTRELLAS  DEV.ESTRELLAS  COMENTARIOS
Modelo                                                                                   
Bus urbano #27         2    18.495   24.99   12.00        5.0       0.707107            2
Piano                  1     4.990    4.99    4.99        3.5       0.000000            0
Playground             1    14.000   14.00   14.00        4.5       0.000000            1
Silla tipo bar         1     4.990    4.99    4.99        3.5       0.000000            0
```

Otra opción (la cual me parece mas refinada) seria...

```
import pandas as pd


diccionario = { 'Modelo': ['Bus urbano #27','Silla tipo bar','Piano','Fuente con flores','Bus urbano #27','Puesto de Yogurt','Playground','Bus urbano #27'],
                 'Usuario': ['Ted Mosby','Art Vandelay','Art Vandelay','Michael','Mark Brendanawicz','Michael','LeCorbusier_2020',''],
                 'Pago': [24.99, 4.99, 4.99, 0, 12, 0, 14, 0],
                 'Estrellas': [5, 3.5,3.5,5,4,5,4.5,1],
                 'Comentario': [True]+[False]*2+[True]*5 }


# Creamos un dataFrame con los datos de «diccionario»
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=diccionario, orient='columns')

# Para los (pagos==0) cambiamos el cero (0) por NaN
df['Modelo']= df['Modelo'].where(df['Pago']>0)
# Eliminamos los valores NaN
df = df.drop('Usuario', axis=1).dropna()


### Agrupamos por 'Modelo' y calculamos: (minimos, maximos, promedios,
# desviaciones std) de las columnas ('Pago' 'Estrellas' 'Comentario')
df = df.groupby('Modelo').agg(['count','min', 'max','mean','std']).fillna(0).sort_index()
```

Después eliminas las columnas innecesarias con:

```
df.drop(('Pago', 'std'), axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.drop(('Pago', 'sum'), axis = 1, inplace = True)
```